# compare list with minimal time complexity in java

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have two list

`List<MyData> listA = new ArrayList<MyData>()` and `List<MyData> listB = new ArrayList<MyData>()` both contain object of type `MyData` and `MyData` contain these variables.

```
Class MyData {
    String name;
    boolean val
}
```

I got to write a program to compare two arraylist are equal or not with less time complexety.I am not overiding equals and hashcode in Mydata class as it an already existing class and modification may effect on different behaviour on application.
Code i wrote is

```
forEach(MyData a:listA ){

    forEach(MyData b:listB ){
        if(a.getName.equals(b.getName)){
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define _equal_ better? Do you want the items to be in same order in both the lists, if so, only a single loop would be enough...

Comment: if both the lists are in same size you can actually use single loop to itereate

Answer (score 1):

First of all `forEach` is not valid Java syntax. It should be `for`.

Second of all, you don't want to have a nested loop, since that would give you `O(n^2)` time complexity.

You should have one loop that iterates over both lists :

```
if (listA.size() != listB.size())
    return false;
for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++){
    MyData a = listA.get(i);
    MyData b = listB.get(i);
    if (!a.getName.equals(b.getName))
        return false;
}
return true;
```

That would give you `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A double foreach loop will give you a complexity in `O(n^2)`... That's not optimal.

Are your lists sorted? if so you could do a comparison one by one (that's a complexity `O(n)`)
If not, sort them! The best generic sorting algorithms have a complexity of `O(n.log(n))`. So overall you will have the same complexity.